# why batching txs is a good idea?

Tags: transactions, account-abstraction

info dump on me, why batching txs is a good idea?
i got this answer from the [Infinitism discord server](https://discord.gg/w89f6VaVG6):

> In general, it can be used to save gas for all the inner txs, that
> will now split both the intrinsic tx cost and some overhead of the
> contract calls. Besides, batching inside a smart account can be used
> to enforce atomicty of operations in the account, or any other
> esoteric properties that you want to enforce. Aggregation in the
> EntryPoint has other potential benefits, like saving gas of calldata
> for signatures.

which is helpful, I need more povs on batching txs in Ethereum in general and in the context of Account Abstraction